# Microcap-12 using Wine 3.03 in Ubuntu 18.04. Can't save files

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I'm trying to run Microcap-12(electronic circuit simulator) with Ubuntu. Until now, the only, but very important, issue, is that I can't save the files.

Info displayed running wine in terminal:

When pressing the save button to open the file explorer dialog:

```
0009:fixme:commdlg:IServiceProvider_fnQueryService Interface {e07010ec-bc17-44c0-97b0-46c7c95b9edc} requested from unknown service {e07010ec-bc17-44c0-97b0-46c7c95b9edc}
0009:fixme:shell:ViewModeToListStyle ViewMode 0 not implemented
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1026, a003, 0, 0x33c178)
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1026, a004, 0, 0x33c178)
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1025, a003, 1, 0x33c178)
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1025, a004, 1, 0x33c178)
0009:fixme:nstc:NSTC2_fnSetControlStyle2 mask & style (0x00000004) contains unsupported style(s): 0x00000004
```

This is the message that appears when I click in some folder in the dialog:

```
0009:fixme:commdlg:IServiceProvider_fnQueryService Interface {e07010ec-bc17-44c0-97b0-46c7c95b9edc} requested from unknown service {e07010ec-bc17-44c0-97b0-46c7c95b9edc}
0009:fixme:shell:ViewModeToListStyle ViewMode 0 not implemented
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1026, a003, 0, 0x33c9f8)
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1026, a004, 0, 0x33c9f8)
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1025, a003, 1, 0x33c9f8)
0009:fixme:shell:IShellBrowser_fnSendControlMsg stub, 0x38b12d0 (2, 1025, a004, 1, 0x33c9f8)
```

This is the message that appears after pressing the save button:

```
0009:fixme:commdlg:IFileSaveDialog_fnGetProperties stub - 0x3913e38 (0x33bd58)
```

The software runs normally, but doesn't save the file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Windows question.

Comment: You could run the program from terminal and see if there are any relevant error messages.

Comment: @sebasth I edited with the information that was displayed in the terminal.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It is a wine question. Windows is an off-topic OS, wine is its emulator on Linux/Unix. These are very different things. Your close vote is a serious mistake.

Comment: I think you would have better answer on Wine forums. I've never seen too much Wine nerd around here. Alcoholic yes, but not that much wine nerd...

Answer (score 3):

Reviving since search engines lead here.

There's an issue for this on the wine bug tracker:
https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48066

Until fixed, the suggested workaround is to set Compatibility to "Windows XP" via winecfg. I've
tested it and it seems to work.